# UITableView not setting style to UITableViewGrouped, sticking to Plain

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am not sure why, but the view controller does not want to be in grouped style.

- There is no xib file for this view controller.
- When init, it is done by initWithStyle:UITableViewGrouped
- debugging the init, it receives the Grouped style
- tried overwriting self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewGrouped];

> ```
>  (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
>     {
>         self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
>         if (self) {
>   //Checking on this line self.tableView.style = UITableViewPlain!!!
>
>
>
>
> (lldb) p style (UITableViewStyle) $1 = UITableViewStyleGrouped 
> (lldb) p [[self tableView] style] (UITableViewStyle) $2 = UITableViewStylePlain
> ```

As you can see, the style says Grouped, I overwritten it with Grouped. Then the next line is Plain?!

Any help is much appreciated. My alternative is to attach a xib to it and hopefully it'll set it that way :S

Thank you in advance

Edit:
This is where i call an instance.

```
AddContactViewController *addContact = [[AddContactViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [addContact setCustomerID:customerID];
    [addContact setDelegate:self];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addContact animated:YES];
```

The initWithStyle above is the AddContactViewController.m and the (lldb) bits are my debug print out.

Hope that clears it a bit better. I can not disclose too much code I'm afraid.

Comment: can you post your complete source code? It's hard to tell what's going wrong in your code

Comment: edited with more information.

Comment: Is `AddContactViewController` really a tableview controller? From the naming, it's not...?

Comment: It is a subclass of UITableViewController yes

Comment: Maybe you should try to use `UIViewController` instead, and create an `UITableView` with `[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]` and add it as a subview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses. I have found an easier solution to my problem.

I added a new xib and called it the same as my controller AddContactViewController.xib. Then in the Interface Builder, I changed the File Owner class to be AddContactViewController.

I added a UITableView in the objects and connected the View from File Owner to UITableView. Then connect up the delegates and datasouce back to file owner.

After that was set up. I changed the style to grouped via the properties on the tableview in IB.

Now that is done. I kept the same creating instances. But in the AddContactViewController I replaced the

```
self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

with

```
self = [super initWithNibName:@"AddContactViewController" bundle:nil];
```

And that was it! I ended up with an extra xib that I will not use, but it was a lot less painful than adding subviews and then handling orientation issues.

Hope that helps everyone else with this weird problem and thank you Ravindra and Owen for their replies.

Answer (score 0):

create your tableviewcontroller by initWithFrame & then assign style UITableViewStyleGrouped to its tableViewStyle property

the last option as per Owen said in comments:
create one ViewController
declare one `UITableView *myTableView` Property with

```
[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]
```

add this myTableView to ViewControoler's view by `[self.view addSubView:myTableView]`

Comment: You can not assign the style after the init.

Comment: According to Apple's documentation, there is no `tableViewStyle` property and the `style` property is read-only, which you can only set it on init. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/style

Comment: do u have added any tableview

Comment: I have no extra tableviews. The tableview shows, just not in grouped style.

Comment: Although, that solution may work, it kind of defeats the purpose of having a UITableViewController. I have similar classes like that if I need more elements on screen. But I have found a solution, without much changes to the code. I will post via an answer for people to try. Thank you for your responses.